# Rails console on a vps returns 'rails new' usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano3, bin

I deployed my app following this [gorails tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04). I can't seem to run a rails console in the current folder.

This works!

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:seed
```

This doesn't

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

The command above returns the usage of 'rails new'.

Note: I'm trying to run these commands in the current folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this in your server:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

Then try

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Permanent solution:

After the first step.

> Copy your bin folder to shared folder.

Then in your capistrano, set that bin folder in linked_dirs.

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/backup tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle}
```

Then deploy again.

So then that updated bin folder will be always served from shared folder and you won't need update your bin every time.